# How to generate the same elasticsearch query using Java Resthighlevel client?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

I am trying to generate a query using the Java RestHighLevelClient of Elasticsearch similar to this:

```
GET /field_search/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "ENTRY_ID": "ttttt"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "MODULE_ID": "xxxxx"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "COMPANY_ID": "22244"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "DELETED": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code that I am using to generate it

```
    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder1 = new BoolQueryBuilder();

    boolQueryBuilder1.must().add(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("MODULE_ID", moduleId));

    boolQueryBuilder1.must().add(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("COMPANY_ID", companyId));

    ........
```

I have skipped some part of it to keep it small. But i use a BoolQueryBuilder and the query it generates is something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "match" : {
          "MODULE_ID" : {
            "query" : "xxxxx",
            "operator" : "OR",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : false,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : false,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match" : {
          "COMPANY_ID" : {
            "query" : "22244",
            "operator" : "OR",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : false,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : false,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match" : {
          "DELETED" : {
            "query" : false,
            "operator" : "OR",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : false,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : false,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "match" : {
          "ENTRY_ID" : {
            "query" : ttttt,
            "operator" : "OR",
            "prefix_length" : 0,
            "max_expansions" : 50,
            "fuzzy_transpositions" : false,
            "lenient" : false,
            "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
            "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : false,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
}
```

It adds additional things into the query. Using the above normal query my results come back correctly but with the java generated query my results are none so how can i build the same query using Java client?

Comment: The stuff it adds are default settings, you shouldn't have to worry about that.

Comment: but the output with it is totally different.. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's different but 100% equivalent

Comment: Why `"query" : ttttt,` missing quotes around `ttttt`?

Comment: @Val you were right the problem was with my code

Answer (score 0):

```
"adjust_pure_negative" : true
```

This is your problem, set it to false or delete it.

Read [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-does-adjust-pure-negative-flag-do/92348) why this happens.

Comment: I tried it didn't make a difference still the same no result